# Does tilting a liquid develop shear stress on its surfaces?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, acceleration, fluid-statics, stress-strain

Please help me these confusions I have.

1. If I tilt a cuboidal container containing an ideal fluid (non viscous liquid), does a shear stress develop on the liquid due to some shearing force acting parallel to bottom of the container? If so, what causes this shear?
2. If a container containing a liquid is horizontally accelerated, its surface gets slanted and the pressure on every point of the free (open) surface is the same as the atmospheric pressure, but shouldn't the pressure on this open surface be different along the direction of motion so that the net pressure difference causes it to accelerate in that direction?

What if I consider a thin tube along the surface then there must a pressure difference on the two ends of the thin tube(hence on the two points of the open surface where the ends of the tube are) because it has an acceleration of $(a\cos x)$, (where $x$ is the angle the surface makes with the horizontal)?

Comment: These questions should probably be left separate again.  Question 2 definitely has answers [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/224234/pressure-difference-along-horizontal-in-accelerated-fluids) ; and questions 1 and 3 are different enough that they shouldn't be together in a question.

Comment: I checked the answer you suggested for my second question, but I don't think it quite answers my question. I am concerned specifically as to why the pressure on the free surface is the same as atmospheric pressure every where on the surface?

Comment: Anyways I removed my third question as you suggested

Comment: The free surface is only exposed to atmospheric pressure.

Comment: But if you consider a thin tube with the free surface as it upper surface then this tube is still accelerating and shouldn't the pressure at the two points on this free surface have different pressures so as to create a net force

Comment: Regarding #2, at each depth, there is a pressure gradient in the direction of the acceleration.  You can determine this pressure gradient using the hydrostatic equation in the vertical , and evaluating the pressure at a given depth at adjacent horizontal locations.  This pressure gradient provides the force imbalance fo the fluid to be accelerated.

Comment: Regarding #1, if the fluid is inviscid, horizontal motion of a surface (parallel to the bottom of the container) will not generate any shear rate (velocity gradient) or any shear stress.