# Why does pressure decreases in the direction of acceleration?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I've read that if a container carrying a liquid is accelerating in horizontal direction then the pressure at same level is not same. It decreases as we move in tge direction of acceleration. Why does the pressure decrease?

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pressure difference along horizontal in accelerated fluids](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/224234/)

Comment: In sketch b, liquid to the rear has more mass in front of it which need to be accelerated.